# Viewing contents of IL2CPP's string_t in xcode's debugger

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, debugging, unity-game-engine

Unity's IL2CPP/LLVM back-end generates cpp files from C#. You can certainly read these files, and drop breakpoints into them to view variables. However C# strings are transcompiled into a custom class called String_t. Xcode doesn't seem to know how to print the inner strings of these classes and I'm not sure how to read the raw bytes.

Here's the String_t definition:

```
struct String_t  : public Object_t
{
    // System.Int32 System.String::length
    int32_t ___length;
    // System.Char System.String::start_char
    uint16_t ___start_char;
};
```

...can anyone figure out how to read the contained string from an Xcode breakpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `p il2cpp::utils::StringUtils::Utf16ToUtf8`.  So if the name of the variable is `L_3` for example, then you can do this:

```
p il2cpp::utils::StringUtils::Utf16ToUtf8(&L_3->___start_char_1)
```

Comment: For me, I had to replace `___start_char_1 ` with `___m_firstChar_1`.

Comment: I'm getting `Function il2cpp::utils::StringUtils::Utf16ToUtf8 has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations.` when trying to do this

Answer (score 2):

You can see the string in memory if you right-click the string in the locals window and select `View Memory of "*foo"`. Then the string starts 12 bytes in. Because of IL2CPP's 16bit characters, the string is printed with dots inbetween. This probably doesn't work for unicode characters!

If anyone has a more robust solution I'd love to accept their answer.

Comment: Seems that the header is now 19 bytes long (with Unity 2018.4.0f1).

Instructions for viewing memory on Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/memory-windows?view=vs-2019.